What is the Theistic response for claiming something other than God is necessary?
In the Argument of Contingency and Leibnizian Cosmological Argument, it is said that there is two types of beings which are necessary and contingent. Some argue that some necessary state can be an alternative to god, so what are theistic responses to this? Why does God have to be necessary existance?

"What is necessary is never unwise."

What if something other than God is necessary like system etc. What is theistic and atheistic responsr to this?

Why should God be necessary rather than other system, if you know or know an article about it, can you help me?

You've mentioned a couple times in here that you want to know these things for certain. You'd probably benefit a lot from reading some of Aquinas's proofs for God. If you're coming from a Christian perspective, while we do believe faith is necessary, especially when making the move to Jesus, Aquinas believed we could know of God's existence intellectually.

Thank you sir, I am not Christian but I accept monotheism. I will read Aquinas.

I'd say the response depends on what they're claiming as the alternative "necessary thing" that is not God.
I'm not an expert at any of this, but I can point to at least one major facet; the necessary being must be eternal.
We have to ask; where time and space themselves come from? As they seem to have beginnings and ends, they seem to have been caused. Because that cause must have existed before time and space existed, that cause must be eternal.
Sometimes people will claim that the universe itself is the necessary thing itself. This has problems, the biggest being that the universe appears to have had a beginning, and seems that it will have an end. So, it misses the criteria of being eternal, for a start (pun intended).
From this point, we can start exploring ideas about this thing being omnipotent, omniscient and omnibenevolent, but that gets tricky and I'm probably not the one to answer those components.
I do think, however, looking at the world we live within and what it consists of and contains, that one can infer the above three components.

I'm not sure I follow the reasoning given here. There seem to be a lot of assumptions like "Because that cause must have existed before time and space existed, that cause must be eternal.". That statement might be true based on what we know, but what we know is very limited.

I totally agree that what we know is very limited! I think the eternal nature of the necessary cause is inferred from its timelessness; something outside of time is, by definition, eternal; it has no beginning or end. If it exists outside of time, it must logically be eternal because no time can come to end it, nor can there be a time before it existed.

What is to say that the birth of time isn't effectively the "stop" of whatever came before? Why would we assume a thing that existed before time can also exist during time (or indeed after)?
Anything before time is effectively in stasis. Similar to how the surface of the Earth is "infinite" if you walk on it, eternity before time exists is technically true but effectively meaningless.

If the birth of time is the "stop" of what came before, you're presupposing a "before" for there to be a stop to occur within. That's the problem. The whole construct of the thing "before" ending is essentially a construct of some "higher" form of time, and you just end up going in circles. The logic isn't that God is before time so much as that God is outside of time, though we might reasonably say both.
We're not talking so much about temporal causation as logical causation; while there may be events higher up the chain, they don't have a temporal seperation.

I don't see why something that is not eternal could not give rise to a universe. My mother is not eternal, but she gave rise to me. In fact, she could have outlived me.

@ScottRowe Because time is a part of that created universe, anything that created it must be outside of time, and anything outside of time is necessarily eternal, as there's no time for it to end within. Your mother, who I assume is very lovely, is herself within time and gave rise to you within time. If she was a truly impressive mother and gave birth to time itself, we might have more questions here, heh.

My mother gave birth to time for me. I can imagine a bigger time with smaller time nested within it, like Russian dolls. No need for a bigger one to be infinitely large.

They say Necessary systems can be alternatives sir. My question is can there be anything else necessary rather than god?

I think the issue you run into is... Well, let's say you have that alternative. That's nifty. You know it's something, you know it's eternal, you know it's omnipotent and omniscient and... Ah. You can call it what you like, but the thing you're describing, the alternative, is what we call God. If it doesn't meet the conditions of being God, it also won't meet the conditions of being a valid alternative. Does that make sense?

Sir but can it not be a metaphysically system which is necessary rather than god. And I believe in God but I am a perfectionist I wanna know it certainly. So please help me about this.

Aquinas would say that the thing you're describing, the "eternal first cause", we refer to as God. We describe it as God. Aquinas would admit that he couldn't quite reach a logical proof for the Catholic Triune God, but at a very minimum, what he felt was proven was God; some being that utterly defies our understanding, of immense and timeless power.

So I think that necessary being exists, but have can I really know that it is God rather than something else?

Again, definitely refer to Aquinas. He breaks down not just that it can't be "something else", but that there is no "something else" you could point to. It's not just "the only possibility is God" in that the other possibilities break down, but there are literally no other possibilities or options to choose from. The Five Ways are really valuable here. If your question is "Is Jesus God?" then that is, inevitably, a matter of faith, though not entirely. Definitely Google the historicity of Jesus for for information there.

I'd invoke the Principle of Sufficient Reason: If the universe exists necessarily, we are still left with the question of why it is necessary. One can either say it is a brute necessity - no underlying reason is available (and violate PSR), or one can provide an explanation.
If it has an explanation, that explanation can assume some be as-yet-undiscovered-physics or it can assume an intentional, eternal creator.
To theists, it seems obvious that positing an eternal god with intentions as necessary is a far more intellectually satisfying answer than "it just is" or "we don't know....yet".
But why is god necessarily existing? Christian theologians would say that god's essence is existence - you cannot have existence without god, they are one and the same. Basically, this view sees God as the unique entity that does not "possess" attributes, but consists as that attribute itself, such that all other instances are derivative of this essence.
Quite a mouthful - and it doesn't get us past the need of brute facts to stop the endless train of "But Why?" (like my 4 year old!)
For non-theists, they can say the initial state of the universe was necessary and that is where a non-theist can draw the line on further questioning.
For a Theist, you need to figure out if god had any choice in what kind of universe he would create. If he was truly free to chose alternatives, then the fact that God chose this particular universe is a brutely contingent fact. If God could only choose to make the actual world we are in, then we back to a brute necessity.
A theist may object and say it is not brutely necessary, since it derives from god's love for life, desire for communion, etc. However, this just serves to push back our demand for explanation: why does god love life, why does god want communion? If they give reasons, we repeat this process again. If not, then we are stating a brute fact, just like the non-theist. We end up in the same place.
Theists have come up with all sorts of ways to somehow have their metaphysical cake and eat it too: we are meant to see god's nature as a logically self-explanatory fact. Unfortunately, I've never seen one of those yet ;-)

I feel like I've got to ask; would you disbelieve your spouse/child/family member, if they told you they loved you but couldn't provide a logical reason why they loved you? Looking for logic in love seems like an odd choice.

Sir I am a perfectionist, I want know something certain rather than possibilities.

@Hido wouldn’t we all ;-P

@Annika I hope I know somethings exactly. I believe in God but I want to testify it.

@ConnieMnemonic well, there is the feeling of love that is partially instinctual/pre-rational. I wouldn't expect a deep/non-circular reason for that any more than for why someone thinks chocolate tastes good. Then then is more dedicated/rational/deliberative love - e.g., the kind that sustains 50 year marriages. That is more than a feeling, it is a choice based on shared history, reciprocity, respect etc -- all very rational things. Also, I've asked my children why they love me, and they have plenty of very sweet reasons ... sometimes my spouse does too ;-)

@Annika +1 for a super adorable answer. Put a big smile on my face. Bless your family, they sound lovely. I also very much agree that love is a choice rather than a feeling. I will say, for the work of philosophy, that pure rationality often leads down dark paths if not tempered by love, and love is not always a rational choice. Love can be made better when it isn't rational, or it can be made worse. Directed towards the good though, love is very beautiful and powerful indeed.

That something other than God is necessary is evident from

The OOO God is self-contradictory (re omni-related paradoxes)
Quasi-scientific falsification (re the problem of evil)

to name a few.  To get to the point the God hypothesis is incoherent and fails as an explantory model. Hence, some other explanation is necessary.
Why is God necessary? For the same reasons why something other than God is; a Godless universe failed to account for all the goings-on in the world (to theists).  Take note, theism arose in a complete theoretical vacuum and at a time when we knew even less.
Come to think of it, a superb question. Marks a point in human history where we graduate from God to ... hypothesis non fingo.

Not a bad answer but as it stands for the wrong question

Also worth noting that there are responses to both these objections. Aquinas has some great stuff to say on these.

@emesupap, apologies ... in my haste, I seem to have swapped the OP's query with my very own.

@ConnieMnemonic, si, I'm aware of them, but these issues I raised with The God Hypothesis does sufficient damage to prompt a search for "better" alternatives to an all-loving, all-knowing, all-powerful Creator.

Maybe it's the best of all possible Gods?

@ScottRowe, that would be a petitio principi, methinks. Que sais-je.

What are the Aquinas responses can someone help me?

@Hido Aquinas' Five Ways.

Thank you sir. Do you have other arguments about this too?

I just wanna know that what are the arguments about God being the only necessary being. Could not this necessary being be a necessary system rather than god?

@Hido, no, sorry. However, not to sound condescending in any way, you can craft your very own, personal argument for/against a motion. I merely responded to the OP's query in a way I felt was appropriate. You were right to bring up Aquinas, he was one of the greatest Theologians and I surmise his canonization was based not on mirabilia as much as it was on his own views on the philosophy in religion.

@Hido, je ne sais pas. That statement you just made leans towards some kind of deism in my view. You're in good company, Einstein was a deist.

Sir actually I am theist but I am not looking for trueness of religion but I am looking for trueness of god's existance. I really appreciate you for helping me sir, thank you I am being for real. Can I ask you this, Lets assume that there is or are necessary beings, why should god be one of them. It could be systems. Thank you again.

If you're a theist then shouldn't you know the answer to your own question? Cogito, it could be (a) "system(s)", but I don't know what you mean by system(s).

What I mean by systems is, we can call it reality or laws or non consciouss being which created us. And thank you for answering.

@Hido, yes if that's what you mean by a "system", it is possible that it's a system that created us.

Sir do you have an answer to this objection, necessary system exists rather than god?

@Hido, Random quantum oscillations in the void? . I have to read Lawrence Kraus' A universe from nothing.

But they derive from existing energy, what I ask is do you have an answer to "necessary system exists rather than god"?

@Hido, well I understood you as necessary that (at least) there's a creative cause and that could be either God or a system

I am not sure about system tho. What I mean by system is non-physical but can still create the universe, eternal, non changing, and existing necessarily. SO what I mean by system is pretty much same as god but system does not have mind.

@Hido, your belief resembles Heraclitean logos, an ordering/creative principle

This is not my belief, this is what can opposition say against, something other than god being necessary. I think that if something is gonna be necessary being, God fits the best. But I am asking that is it possible for system to be like that.   And what I mean by necessary being is, necessary being is eternal, independant of outer sourcea, it is not created, it exista by its own nature, it has to exist in every possible world.

@Hido, I csn see how that'll work: simply a system, lacking any intentionality so to speak and indeed, it would be necessary to ground reality (all that is).

Sir but it is non-physical just like god but only difference between it amd god is one has mind the other doesn't.
